# How to add attribute using AG Grid at row and cell level?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Just like we can add CSS class using AG Grid. Is there any way in ag grid to add attribute(s) at row and cell level?

```javascript
const gridOptions = {
// all rows assigned CSS class 'my-green-class'
rowClass: 'my-green-class',

// all even rows assigned 'my-shaded-effect'
getRowClass: params => {
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
        return 'my-shaded-effect';
    }
},

// other grid options ...
```

For example I want something like `my-custom-attr="dummyValue"` below:

```html
<div comp-id="44" my-custom-attr="dummyValue"
     style="transform: translateY(0px); height: 42px;" row-index="0"
     aria-rowindex="2"
     class="ag-row-even ag-row-no-focus ag-row ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first"
     role="row" row-id="0">
    <div comp-id="63"
         class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-normal-height ag-cell-value"
         tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" col-id="sickDays"
         unselectable="on" style="left: 200px; width: 200px;">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into cell renders.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-rendering/

You could then add your attr to the cell by returning

```
return (
    <div my-attr="asdffasdf">
        {params.data.cellValue}
    </div>
)
```